# XSLT2 - Get text of all nodes except certain ones

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to get the text of a whole HTML looking document but I would like to exclude certain nodes from the retrieval.

## XML

```
<body>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text <img src="whatever"><alt>alt title</alt></p>
  <div>
     <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

## Context

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsl:template match="/">

   <html>
     <body>
       <table>
         <xsl:for-each select="collection(...)"> 
           <xsl:variable name="text" select="string(//body)" />
              <tr>
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="$text"/></td>
              </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        <table>
      </body>
   </html>

  </xsl:template>
</stylesheet>
```

## Expected result

I want everything but the `alt` element so `some text`*3 = 29 in this example.

I am doing this operation from a `for-each` on a `collection` of file.
So right now I just do a `string(/body)` to get everything in each of my file.

I was thinking of a recursive call:

```
 <xsl:function name="lp:gettext">
    <xsl:param name="n" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$n/child::node()">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(text(),lp:gettext($n/child::node()))" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$n/name()='alt'" />
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>
```

But I can't seem to use `child::` in a function it seems, or not like I do.

How can I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Please add a sample XML of what you would like to obtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="alt"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to your input (after closing the `img` tag!) returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
some textsome text some text
```

This is because the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule) copy all text nodes to the output - so all you need to do is override the default behaviour for the nodes you don't want to be copied.

---

### Added:

Based on the stylesheet you have added to your question, I believe the following should do what you want (I cannot test it):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="collection(...)"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="alt"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Right, but I'm inside a for-each, called by a template matching `/`, therefor all templates will apply to the reference document, not my collection files, right?

Comment: You need to call `xsl:apply-templates` and select the nodes you want to extract the text from.

Comment: I have tried that, but that cannot solve my problem. I am running my XSL file on an XML file that has not much to do with my collection of files.
All templates that I write will be applied on my target XML file (not sure how you call it) and will not be applied to the nodes I get from my `for-each` as I already am in my main template.

Comment: @Flag Templates are applied to the nodes you select in the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction. If you want to process the collection, apply templates to that.

Comment: Then I don't know how to do that. I've tried apply my template before calling the string function, it didn't change my result. If you can post an example based on my context, that would be great!

Comment: I stuck to the function instead as it was more straight forward in my case, but your solution was good and taught me something! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i just found this [remove-elements-deep](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_remove-elements-deep.html) function that seems to do exactly what I want.

Comment: That's a very clumsy solution. If you're using XSLT you really need to master the use of template rules which are the key weapon in your armoury.